# Group and generates unique identifier based on value

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df.1 <- data.frame (value = c(1, 1, 90, 1, 1, 32, 1, 1, 1)) %>%
```

I want to group the data so that the group number changes when `value` is greater than 1.
In df the first value is always 1.

Expected results:

```
> df.2
  value nr.group
1     1        1
2     1        1
3    90        2
4     1        2
5     1        2
6    32        3
7     1        3
8     1        3
9     1        3
```

`consecutive_id` does not produce the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
df.1$nr.group <- cumsum(df.1$value > 1) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use `cumsum` on the boolean `df.1$value > 1`:

```
df.1["group"] <- cumsum(df.1$value > 1) + 1
```

Output:

```
  value group
1     1     1
2     1     1
3    90     2
4     1     2
5     1     2
6    32     3
7     1     3
8     1     3
9     1     3
```